# Uno is not working for existing PCL project. uwp error is giving for .NetStandar 2.0

Tags: uno

We have added UNO in our existing project created in Visual studio 2019( using .NetStandard). we have set target and min version for UWP as per BugTracker sample project but we are getting below error while running the .wasm project.

Severity              Code     Description        Project  File        Line              Suppression State

> Error     NU1201              Project XXXXXX.UWP is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project ImageViewerPOC.UWP supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)        XXXXXX.Wasm              D:UnoXXXXXXX.WasmXXXXXX.Wasm.csproj        1

Answer (score 0):

In order to use **.NET Standard 2.0** in **UWP**, you need to target Fall Creators Update (FCU) as the minimum version of your UWP project. That’s because **.NET Standard 2.0** contains many APIs that require **FCU** to make them work in the context of the **UWP** execution environment, specifically **AppContainer**.

[image]

Comment: I have set target version Fall Creators Update as minimum target version but it is not working.

Comment: Hi Arpit which project should I add as reference in .Wasm project. Should I add UWP or PCL. If I uwp then it will give not compatible with netstandard2.0. and if I PCL project then it will open browser but throws exception of index page not found.